# Can I get the edit history of a post using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the edit history of a post using the Facebook APIs? How about edit the caption of a photo?

A bug somewhere between iPhoto's uploader and Facebook changed the captions on all of my Facebook pictures but all of the old captions exist in the edit history. I'm trying to devise a software solution.

Comment: Did you ever work out how to obtain a posts history via the api? So far I have only found the last update date of a post but no version history.